# Python- how do I use re to match a whole string

Tags: python, string, match

I am validating the text input by a user so that it will only accept letters but not numbers. so far my code works fine when I type in a number (e.g. 56), it warns me that I should only type letters and when I type in letters it doesn't return anything (like it should do). My problem is that it accepts it when I start by typing letters followed by numbers e.g. (s45). what it does is accept the first letter but not the whole string. I need it to accept the whole string.

```
def letterCheck(aString):
    if len(aString) > 0:
        if re.match("[a-zA-Z]", aString) != None:
            return ""
    return "Enter letters only"
```

Comment: Well you have return empty, and try adding `+` to the end of your regular expression.

Comment: no, the return part is fine. its meant to return nothing if it passes the validation test.

Comment: Why are you not just using `aString.isalpha()`?

Comment: That's not the problem, but it's a fairly bad design IMO; return a boolean and print the error message in the calling code if necessary...

Comment: The question title is misleading, solutions address the problem described which is not how to match a whole string.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Anchor it to the start and end, and match *one or more* characters:

```
if re.match("^[a-zA-Z]+$", aString):
```

Here `^` anchors to the start of the string, `$` to the end, and `+` makes sure you match 1 or more characters.

You'd be better off just using [`str.isalpha()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalpha) instead though. No need to reach for the hefty regular expression hammer here:

```
>>> 'foobar'.isalpha()
True
>>> 'foobar42'.isalpha()
False
>>> ''.isalpha()
False
```

Comment: Do you need this: `^` with re.match? Isn't it implied?

Comment: @buffer: yes, it is implied; I prefer an explicit anchor however as you absolutely need the `$`, and too many people trip over the difference between `re.search()` and `re.match()`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters : That's a good suggestion. I couldn't infer from the documentation if there can be any side effect of placing `^` with `re.match`

Answer (score 5):

use boundaries in your regex + raw string to encode the regex, like this:

```
r"^[a-zA-Z]+$"
```

Answer (score 3):

You might consider using isalpha() on the string. It returns true if the string contains nothing but alphabetic characters, false otherwise.

```
if aString.isalpha():
   do something
else:
   handle input error
```

Comment: A nice property of `isalpha()` for this application is that it returns `False` for empty strings, so the separate test for that is no longer needed.

Comment: thank you all for your speedy answers, they all have helped me solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

if you look for pretty pythonic writings, go for isalpha and isdecimal :

```
str = u"23443434";
print str.isdecimal();
```